# How to load ascx from WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webmethod, aspx-user-control

I've been struggling to load an .ascx (User Control) after a WebMethod has completed the SQL task.

The WebMethod is triggered by an Ajax Function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        $(".use-address").on("click", function () {
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var $text = $row.find(".nr").text();
            var $table = $(this).closest('table').attr('id')

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "wbfMain.aspx/register_activity",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id_permission: $text, _selected_table: $table }),
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
    });
});

public partial class wbfMain : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static Control myControl = new Control();
    public static Control myControl_E = new Control();
    public static Control myControl_L = new Control();
    public static PlaceHolder plch = new PlaceHolder();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plch = placeHolder;
        myControl_E = Page.LoadControl("wbucEntradas.ascx");
        myControl_L = Page.LoadControl("wbucSalidas.ascx");
        placeHolder.Controls.Clear();
        myControl = Page.LoadControl("wbucWelcome.ascx");
        placeHolder.Controls.Add(myControl);
    }

    protected void lkLoadEntradas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plch.Controls.Clear();
        plch.Controls.Add(myControl_E);
    }

    protected void lkLoadSalidas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        plch.Controls.Clear();
        plch.Controls.Add(myControl_L);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void register_activity(int id_permission, string _selected_table)
    {
        wbfMain main = new wbfMain();
        clsSQLCommands SQLCommands = new clsSQLCommands();
        SQLCommands.SQL_register_activity_time(id_permission, (_selected_table == "detailTable") ? 1 : 2);
        if(_selected_table== "detailTable")
        {
            //Doesn't load the User control
            plch.Controls.Clear();
            plch.Controls.Add(myControl_L);
        }
        else
        {
            //Doesn't load the user control
            plch.Controls.Clear();
            plch.Controls.Add(myControl_E);
        }
    }
}
```

After the WebMethod triggers the user control, the User control has a Page_Load inside, which request an HTML string from a Database to create a table

```
public partial class wbucSalidas : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        clsSQLCommands SQLCommands = new clsSQLCommands();
        protected string MyString { get; set; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = SQLCommands.SQL_SP_Get_Daily_Activity(1);
            MyString = test;
        }
    }
```

The User control Page_Load triggers the following 2 methods

```
public string SQL_SP_Get_Daily_Activity(int option)
        {
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            string htmlInfo = "";
#if DEBUG
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EAMStringDebug"].ConnectionString))
#else
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EAMString"].ConnectionString))
#endif
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_get_daily_activity", conn))
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@option", SqlDbType.Int).Value = option;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.Fill(data);
                htmlInfo = ConvertDataTableToHTML(data);
            }
            return htmlInfo;
        }

        public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
        {
            string html = "";
            html += "<thead><tr>";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                html += "<td>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>";
            html += "<td>" + "Registro de Actividad" + "</td>";
            html += "</tr></thead>";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                html += "<tbody><tr>";
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if(j == 0)
                    {
                        html += "<td class='nr'>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
                    }
                    else
                        html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
                    if (j + 1 == dt.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        html += "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary use-address' runat='server'>Seleccionar</button>" + "</td>";
                    }
                }
                html += "</tr></tbody>";
            }
            return html;
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is to load the ("wbucSalidas.ascx") if the value received in _selected_table is "detailTable", the problem is that once in the if condition nothing happens, I'd really appreciate any help you can provide me.

**Note:** There is no problem to load the user control when the ASP Linkbutton is clicked, the problem is during the WebMethod

Comment: myControl_L will be null when WebMethod is called. In your link button clicked, the `Page_Load` fires first and then runs your link button event handler, With WebMethod, you don't get a full postback so your `Page_Load` never runs, which means you don't populate your variable

Comment: How can I trigger the Page_Load before adding the user control to the PlaceHolder?

Comment: You can't. It has been a good 6 years since I've done WebForms but from my understanding, WebMethod is basically used for your Ajax calls, where you don't have a full postback. Not sure if you can just do `Page.LoadControl("wbucSalidas.ascx");` in your WebMethod but I could be wrong.

Comment: I tried that yesterday but same problem, it didn't load the UC `main.Page.LoadControl("wbucSalidas.ascx");`